# Correlation coefficient percentage is low considering relationship between variables

Tags: regression, correlation, linear, r-squared

I am creating a model in R Studio for NCAA football games and am encountering values that seem lower than they should be.  Here is my function and returned R-squared value.

```
lm(formula = rushing_yards ~ yards_per_rush_attempt, data = games.box)
```

This is the end of the model summary:

```
Multiple R-squared:  0.778, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7779
```

While 78% is nothing to scoff at I would have thought it would have been higher considering how closely related `rushing_yards` and `yards_per_rush_attempt` are to each other.  Am I missing something?  Is something wrong with my dataset or should I not worry about the results?

[image]

Comment: I would have thought the correlation of about $0.882$ was high, since you need to consider that the number of rush attempts will not be constant

Comment: What does your scatterplot look like? Would answer a lot of doubts by taking a quick peak and sharing it here.

Comment: Scatterplot added above.

Answer (score 0):

Yards per rush explains a lot of the variation in rush yards per game but leaves some of that variation explained. Another source of variation, not considered in your model, is how many rush attempts per game, so it is unsurprising that you leave some of the variation unexplained.

I think I agree with the comment that your $R^2$ is surprisingly high for a model that does not consider rush attempts, but you have such a simple model that I don’t believe there to be any overfitting concerns.

Comment: So after adding rushing_attempts the R2 increases significantly.                                    
                                                                                                                                          
   Multiple R-squared:  0.962, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9619

Comment: @AaronMorris I’m not surprised. Those are the determinants of rushing yards in a game. The only reason you have any errors is because you should be multiplying them instead of adding.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.  This is the result after multiplying.                                               
                                                                                                                                   
          Multiple R-squared:  0.9998, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9998.

Comment: Your predictions would probably be perfect if not for some rounding issues (which are just part of your data, nothing to do with poor modeling by you).